# Match if partial part of string exists in another column e.g. if AUD exists in one column highlight AUDUSD

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-conditional-formatting

Hopefully someone can help me with a google sheets formula to look up a currency in a column of currency pairs, I'm sure it's fairly basic but because it needs a partial match as the news will always be a single currency and the list of pairs will always be two currencies put together I am struggling to do this.

How my sheet is structured; I have a list of currency pairs in one column, the next column is what I'm trying to do. In the "news ?" column the value = "News" if the previous currency pair matches with any the values in H20 to H25. The value = "No News" if the currency pair does not contain any values in H20 to H25. In this example, these values are AUD and CAD as we have news on these currencies today to be wary of.

```
1  | Currency pairs | News ?
2  | AUDUSD         | News
3  | EURUSD         | No News
4  | GBPUSD         | No News
5  | USDCAD         | News
6  | USDCHF         | No News
7  | USDJPY         | No News
8  | AUDCAD         | News
9  | AUDCHF         | News
10 | AUDJPY         | News
11 | AUDNZD         | News
12 | AUDSGD         | News
13 | CADCHF         | News
14 | CADJPY         | News
15 | CHFJPY         | No News
```

etc...

And I have a column of currencies which has news occurring today e.g.

```
H19 | Today we have news on
H20 | AUD
H21 | CAD
H22 |
H23 |
H24 |
H25 |
```

My question is: How do I highlight via a formula if one part of the currency pair appears in the news column. Can be conditional formatting or a value in the next column as per the example which says "News" or "No News" (or 1 or 0, tick or cross, doesn't really matter as long as it flags if it matches with the news)

The tricky part is the currency pairs column will always be the six character pairs and the news column will always just be one single three-letter currency.

The news column will have anywhere between 0 news and say 5 rows of currencies which have news

I have tried things like this with no success so far:

```
=VLOOKUP(H20:H25&"*",A2,1,0)

=IF(REGEXMATCH(A2, H20:H25&"*"), 1, 0)

=if(COUNT(find(H20:H25,A2))=1,CHAR(10004))
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Sorry I have tried to clarify, my questions is how do I highlight via a formula if one part of the currency pair appears in the news column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

formula in **B2** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A15, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A20:A25)), "News", "No News"))
```

custom conditional formatting formula:

```
=REGEXMATCH($A2, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, $A$20:$A$25))
```

[image]